# Array size bigger than elements stated

Tags: c++, arrays

I created an array with 9 elements but when I run the code it says the size of the array is actually 36. Why is it 36 instead of 9?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    float ar[] =
    {
        0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f,
        0.4f, 0.5f, 0.6f,
        0.7f, 0.8f, 0.9f
    };

    std::cout << "array size = " << sizeof(ar) << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ar); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "array (" << i << ") = " << ar[i] << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
array size = 36
array (0) = 0.1
array (1) = 0.2
array (2) = 0.3
array (3) = 0.4
array (4) = 0.5
array (5) = 0.6
array (6) = 0.7
array (7) = 0.8
array (8) = 0.9
array (9) = 1.26117e-044
array (10) = 3.85682e-039
array (11) = 1.#QNAN
array (12) = 3.85687e-039
array (13) = 5.88404e-039
array (14) = 0
array (15) = 7.20267e-043
array (16) = 6.6267e+031
array (17) = 5.88404e-039
array (18) = 1.4013e-045
array (19) = 1.5076e-038
array (20) = 1.50692e-038
array (21) = 2.8026e-045
array (22) = 0
array (23) = 3.85687e-039
array (24) = 8.71369e+031
array (25) = 1.#QNAN
array (26) = 3.85694e-039
array (27) = 5.88418e-039
array (28) = 1.4013e-045
array (29) = 0
array (30) = 0
array (31) = 0
array (32) = 0
array (33) = 0
array (34) = 0
array (35) = 6.91554e+031
```

My post doesn't need more details stop asking for more text
My post doesn't need more details stop asking for more text
My post doesn't need more details stop asking for more text
My post doesn't need more details stop asking for more text

Comment: Hint #1: 36 = 9 * 4.  Hint #2: sizeof(float) = 4.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ar)/sizeof(ar[0]); i++)`

Comment: .. . because `sizeof(float)` is 4 on your system ?

Comment: Please don't deface questions (or any post for that matter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sizeof(ar);
```

returns the size of an array *in bytes*. To get the number of elements, you need to divide by the size of each element:

```
int numElt = sizeof(ar) / sizeof(ar[0]);
```

C arrays offer a lot of surprises, you should usually use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Comment: I prefer using `int numElt = sizeof(ar) / sizeof(ar[0]);`, for the cases that I may change the type of elements inside an array (e.g. `float` -> `double`).

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I thought it was like the vector class and expected to get an out of bounds error if it went over the real size. Cheers